# How to align a dropdown menu in CSS

Tags: html, css, menu, alignment, dropdown

I'm having some trouble aligning my dropdown menu in my angular app.

Please see the screenshot attached. The menu extends too far right of the screen. I need it to align to the "top right" of the ellipses instead of the "top left" as it is currently. The menu is currently functioning in a table.

Any assistance in getting the menu to shift to the left would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Dropdown menu]

```
Here is the HTML/CSS: 
              <td class="dropup">
                <div class="dropup">
                  <button style="background-color: white;" class="dropbtn">
                    <img class="icon" src="assets/ellipsis.png">
                  </button>
                  <div class="dropup-content">
                    <a href="#">Admin Functionality</a>
                    <a href="#" (click)="downloadBucket(j._id)"> Download Project Snapshot</a>
                    <a [routerLink]="['/project/'+j._id+'/project-activity']">View Project Activity</a>
                    <a href="#">Archive Project</a>
                    <a *ngIf="j.creatorid != user._id" (click)="onLeaveProjectClick(j._id, j.projectname, n)">Leave Project</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>

    .dropbtn {
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}
.dropup {
  position: relative; 
  display: inline-block;
  float:right;
}
.dropup-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 60% 40%;
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.dropup-content :hover {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.dropup-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropup-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #00aca8 !important;
}
.dropup:hover .dropup-content {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you set `.dropup-content` to `absolute`, it will be left aligned relative to `.dropup` as `.dropup-content` is within `.dropup`. But as your class is already absolute, simply add:

`right: 0;
left: auto; // Unsure if you really need this though`

to `.dropup-content`. This will take care that the class is right aligned relative to `.dropup`.

Answer (score 1):

add to class .dropup-content this:

```
  right:0;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b1stpfr4/2/